# Contador usando o update no WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Estou tentando criar um contador, porém o código não esta incrementando mais um, poderiam me ajudar?

```
$wpdb->update('QuantidadeTestes', array('QtdTeste' => QtdTeste+1), array('idUsuario' => $user_info->ID), array('%s'),array('%d'));
```